# Google Play Install Referrer missing campaignid in some responses

Tags: android, google-ads-api, install-referrer

We are using Google Play Install Referrer library for Install Attribution.
The working referrer value we get from this is :

> network=g&campaignid=863200068&loc_physical_ms=9061947&adsplayload=CAAYBSAB&gclid=CjwKCAjw9sreBRBAEiwARroYmx78Bsi3sKQIq1bqJ-Wak4ZMv5cH7fFPzpBWEmZo2xwDR4b6MGe8zRoCRMYQAvD_BwE&conv=848318015

In this response **campaignid** param helps us to attribute the installation to a particular Google Ad campaign.

Recently we observed that many of the attributions were missing and on further investigation we found that Google Play Install Referrer library was reporting the referrer value as follows :

> adsplayload=CAEYEyAB&ai=CDc7RJknTW9izF8eGwgOb1JXoCKCtv_tTmJzlxdsH3uXAxvwJEAEgufrrQSgCYOXq4wOgAb-cwZQDqQLNQSZoGztNPqgDAaoExAFP0HSFlXr3wwLexHjogJ_YwsAeNo13eqHnvnt-7JCoBqHlhrMyN22uboUAuWhYwG95T-9EGNZVxTYOa8ka2U96AkppPtSbgO03MFaZ2cP5U9RhqBaSevkJDzCpHu14yi4ySZoaXq9mzJEre3eXf9E4dQFkGbgNhlkD5hQ0etd3348oU6W9c46_0E4p6y6Ar8i8q2QO4cT13pZ42cE-MZQd4qOwPBduqJHNY4t1UDiFjbYhfJLZyQzKMK5b16tkCQOGh1T6wAT287OG3AGIBdiL4PYFkAYBoAYasAYBgAep475riAcBkAcCmAcBqAemvhuoB9XJG6gHoQGoB63KG6gHrs0bqAfZyxuoB8_MG7gHpZnd596nq90OwAfl1APAB5zVA8AHmNUD2AcB-gcWY29tLmVkbW9iaWxlbGFicy5zbGluZ5gIAaAI_MA9sAgCuAgB0ggGCAAQAhgCsQk9zYd58BoQVbgT4QKCFCwaKm1vYmlsZWFwcDo6MTAwMDAtY2EtYXBwLWdvb2dsZS1wbGF5LXNlYXJjaA&gclid=CjwKCAjw9sreBRBAEiwARroYm9OtvIFxn_V_vTJt_m9aRUwj3lFjGQlxUQgh0SucwOQv7uSCv8JP7BoCKhMQAvD_BwE&conv=848318015

The parameter **campaignid** is completely missing from this. What can be the reason for this? And what could be solution for overcoming this issue ?

Apart from this, we have observed that the params **adsplayload** and **conv** are always present in these cases.

- What are these params(Any link for documentation of all these params)
  ?
- Is it safe to assume that in case these 2 params are not empty then the attribution is for Google Ad ?

Comment: I have same question

Comment: Have you resolved it?

Comment: @LeoNguyen not yet, but i am assuming that if the params adsplayload and conv are present then its from Google Ads so marking their utmSource. In this way even if i am missing which particular campaign they belong to, i am able to know that they were from Google Ads and not others or organic

Comment: Bounce - any new insight?

Comment: I've been gathering play install referrer data since before I launched ads.  I'm finding I had referrer data with conv and adsplayload before I started my own campaign.  So unless someones doing ads for me--I don't think conv/adsplayload is a reliable way.